# calendar not working when hosted on ftp ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

when i try to open asp.net calender on local host it work fine but when i hosted it on ftp after publishing my project,calender encounters an error as 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'.what can we do?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code snippets? And what are the globalization settings of your localhost and server?

Comment: when i click on calender for online,its shows stack trace.i guess calender click should open calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has probably to do with your globalization settings, try to override your system settings in the web.config so you are sure that on both machines you have the same settings. For example:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

On the page below you find more info:

[How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)